# Can a wizard Accio (Summoning Charm) the Elder Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

Can a wizard use Accio (the Summoning Charm) on the Elder Wand?
In the Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them film, we see Tina Goldstein summon the wand of Graves

> (who is actually Grindelwald in disguise)

from him after Newt immobilizes him? Can the same be done to the Elder Wand?

Comment: Assuming you know what and where it is... sure, why not.

Comment: Elder Wand is no different than any other wand (apart from it being all-powerful).  So i guess you can; depending on how far it is.

Answer (score 9):

## It’s unclear if Accio would work on the Elder Wand.

Accio did work on at least some wands - Hermione used it to summon Harry’s wand when he’d lost it.

> “Accio wand!’ cried Hermione. Harry’s wand flew from a dark corner into her hand and she threw it to him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 35 (Beyond the Veil)*</sup></sub>

However, items can be enchanted to prevent Accio from working on them.

> “Oh, it could still be here, but under counter-enchantments,’ said Hermione. ‘Charms to prevent it being summoned magically, you know.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 10 (Kreacher’s Tale)*</sup></sub>

The Invisibility Cloak was immune to Accio, so it is possible that the Elder Wand, another one of the Hallows, may be as well.

> “*‘Accio Cloak!’* roared one of the Death Eaters.
>
> Harry seized its folds, but it made no attempt to escape: the Summoning Charm had not worked on it.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 28 (The Missing Mirror)*</sup></sub>

Without a confirmed example of the Elder Wand either being successfully Summoned or failing to be Summoned, it’s impossible to say for sure whether Accio would work on it.

## We do know the Elder Wand can be removed by Expelliarmus.

The Elder Wand certainly isn’t immune to all spells that would move it from its master. Draco successfully used Expelliarmus to disarm Dumbledore before failing to kill him like he’d been ordered to do.

> “The door burst open and somebody erupted through it and shouted: *‘Expelliarmus!’*
>
> Harry’s body became instantly rigid and immobile, and he felt himself fall back against the Tower wall, propped like an unsteady statue, unable to move or speak. He could not understand how it had happened – *Expelliarmus* was not a Freezing Charm –
>
> Then, by the light of the Mark, he saw Dumbledore’s wand flying in an arc over the edge of the ramparts and understood …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 27 (The Lightning-Struck Tower)*</sup></sub>

Though this doesn’t show whether Accio would work on it, it does show it’s not immune to all spells.